# Group/organize program icons and files on the desktop

Tags: file-management

I’m looking for a simple tool (Windows, Linux and/or Mac) that allows me to make my desktop more clean by grouping and organizing my desktop application icons and files in directories the same way as [Android](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/09/07/how-to-create-folders-in-android-beginners-guide/) and iOS.

I know I could simply create folders on the desktop using native methods (e.g. on Windows: right-click, select "New", then "Folder"). I don't like this way because the folder will be opened in other filesExplorer view unlike Android for example open in just a **local pop-up**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac, Launchpad: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202635

It works exactly like Android/IOS, and it is standard on newer Mac OS X Lion and Mountain Lion. I'm not sure of the status on Mavericks but seeing as Apple favors user experience, they probably kept at least some of the functionality.

On Windows, WinLaunch (http://winlaunch.org/) closely mirrors Launchpad. It is a platform for organizing apps in an Android-like manner.

On Linux, Gnome-Shell behaves in a **similar** manner, but it doesn't allow grouping of Apps directly on the overview. Details can be seen at Gnome's App Folders Configuration Blog post (https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/17/app-folder-configuration/) and can be resumed in a single sentence: Use the application **gnome-software** to create folders and add apps to folders.

Link to the gnome-software website: (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software)

As everything Linux, it requires some know-how and some setting up, but that comes from a culture and as such I believe it is the best option for people using Linux.

As usual, Ubuntu has a more "user-friendly" interface for this, called "Launch Folders". Since this is specific to Ubuntu's Unity Desktop Environment and somewhat distanced from the rest of the Linux Community I decided to give it its own paragraph. It's also worth to note that Unity is based on Gnome Shell, thus there will be many similarities. The website: http://unity-folders.exceptionfound.com/

I'm not going to give my opinion on other Linux Desktop Environments as I do not consider myself experienced enough on them.

If there's anything else worth mentioning, I'll happily add it to the answer. :D

Comment: Thanks Fermando for your efforts and your clean response, I prefer I'll find a tool that regroup app icons directly on desktop area :P

Comment: Stardock Fences may be what you are looking for:
http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/

And no need to thank me, it is a very interesting idea and it piqued my interest. :D

Comment: yes It's a great tool ;)