# How to group Windows desktop icons like Android?

Tags: windows, desktop-environment

I see this has been [asked](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/group-organize-program-icons-and-files-on-the-desktop) and [answered](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/18905/12102) before but I am more interested to see if there are Windows apps where we can group desktop icons like Android allow, rather than using a macOS Launchpad experience on Windows.

Comment: This question is inaccurate. You can group icons with just folders. Are you also asking for an app that shows a popup? Or what's the feature that's missing for you? Questions shouldbe self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Create a New Folder, drag and drop all the shortcuts you want into the folder. Optionally you can [change the icon](https://www.lifewire.com/change-folder-icons-in-windows-11-5200732#:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20the%20folder%20and,selection%20when%20you%27ve%20decided.) of the new folder to whichever icon you like.